# Cannot update Linux with pacman

Tags: linux, arch-linux, software-update, pacman

Trying to update my Artix (Arch derived) Linux from the command line with:

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

I get the following error:

```
...
Total Download Size:       3.15 MiB
Total Installed Size:  15628.07 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:        678.21 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
:: Retrieving packages...
 khtml-5.79.0-1-x86_64                                      2.8 MiB  3.09 MiB/s 00:01 [-------------------------------------------------]  88%
 kross-5.79.0-1-x86_64                                      3.1 MiB  3.02 MiB/s 00:01 [-------------------------------------------------]  99%
(1096/1096) checking keys in keyring                                                  [-------------------------------------------------] 100%
(1096/1096) checking package integrity                                                [-------------------------------------------------] 100%
error: khtml: signature from "Artix Buildbot <buildbot@artixlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/khtml-5.79.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: kross: signature from "Artix Buildbot <buildbot@artixlinux.org>" is invalid
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/kross-5.79.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] n
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

I get the same error if at the last two questions I reply with a Yes.

I would like to update my system ignoring these two packages. How can I do it? Is it possible that these two, non critical, 6 MiB packages block a 15 GiB update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retried today, and the update has been successful.

I did not delete this question since it may be a common issue, even if the solution is trivial.